# Can i connect android emulator to my network?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, android-emulator

i need to create method that finds all connected devices in my network, but since emulator uses virtual network, i can't find any.

Is there a way to have emulator connected to my network instead of virtual one?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Configure Hyper-V in the machine as given below.

[image]

After installation you will need to restart the machine.
Then Install Android SDK tools from Visual Studio as Go `Tools–>Android–>Android SDK Manager`

In there install all the packages with android support.
Then connect your phone with `Developer` option enabled and the `visual studio` will detect your device automatically.

Comment: Maybe i asked the question wrong. My emulator is working i have app running on it. The problem is that it is running with virtual router. I need to ping all devices(ip's) connected to my network but since it is running with virtual router i am not able to ping them.